# How do I see/change my github settings that is attached to keychain access?

Tags: git, macos, github, keychain, git-config

I know my settings are tied to osxkeychain because I get that as a result after `git config credential.helper`

I followed this [site](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/) and opened up keychain access app and looked for github.com but didn't find anything. How can I change my settings from here? I ultimately want to setup another Github account so I can mess around and really learn Github.

Answer (score 0):

Just a possibility. Have you selected "All Items" on the side bar of the Keychain Access app before searching "github"? I can find my github login info in it.

Comment: yeah, i have all items selected